# How to set a write deadline for GoLang bufio.Writer?

Tags: go, networking, tcp, io, network-programming

I am using `buffio.Writer` in GoLang as follows.

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address) // address is of form ip:port
w := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
w.WriteByte(code) // code is a byte
w.Write(data) // data is a byte buffer
w.Flush()
```

I am trying to modify the above code so that the `write()` events have a deadline: when the deadline is passed, the `write()` event will return irrespective of the fact that it was successful or not.

In GoLang its possible to have a deadline, if the `conn` (connection object) is directly used for writing using `conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(n * time.Second))`. However, when I use `bufifo.writer` object, which is essentially a wrapper around `conn` for buffered IO, there is no API to set a deadline.

While its possible to use `conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(n * time.Second))` and use `conn.Write(b)`, its very inefficient since it doesn't buffer the `write` events (thus a lot of context switches)

Is there a way in GoLang where I can use buffered IO with a `writeDeadline()`?

Thanks

Comment: If you set a deadline for `conn`, and you wrap it in `bufio.Writer`, writing to the wrapper will also report an error, because it calls `conn.Write()` under the hood, which will report an error. `bufio.Writer` does not swallow that error.

Comment: @icza Thanks. I think your approach should work.

Comment: Canceling I/O ops is non-trivial, as you've found. [This article](https://medium.com/@zombiezen/canceling-i-o-in-go-capn-proto-5ae8c09c5b29) runs through some techniques for per operation cancelation.

Comment: @colm.anseo Thanks! This is a really useful reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases to note here.

If you want to have per `write()` deadline, then its not possible to use buffering. When you use buffering, then the actual `write()` is triggered when the buffer is full. So technically its not possible to know when your `write()` is completed. In this case, you are essentially using `conn.write()` and you can use `conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(n * time.Second))`.

In the second case, as @icza has mentioned in the comment, you can set the deadline in the underlying `conn` object, and the buffio.writer() wrapper will adhere to this rule. While this is semantically correct, it doesn't provide the networking abstraction you want.